# multithreaded linked list in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, linked-list, singly-linked-list

First a little explanation of what I am trying to do:

My plan is to write a program with a socket stream implemented using the boost::asio library which feeds data to a parser implemented using boost:spirit::qi.  The parser will take the packets and fill a packet object and then append that object to the end of a linked list of packet objects.  The packet processor will read the first object in the list and do its processing and then move onto the next item and delete the first.

I decided to use a linked list because a if I used a std::queue I would have to lock the entire container every time the stream added a packet or the processor removed one which would make the two threads run more or less serially, which I would like to avoid.  Plus the queue class has a tendency to copy the entire objects whereas the linked list idea has the benefit of creating the object once and then just pointing to it.  To avoid serializing this whole business I intend to place boost:mutex mutexes in each node and locking them from there.  The idea is to have the socket stream create the list and immediately lock the first node, populate the node from the parser, create the next node and lock it, then unlock the first node and move on to the next node to do work.  This way there's never an unlocked node dangling at the end that the packet procesor may jump to and delete under the socket streams nose.  The packet processor will check the first node and try to lock it, if it locks it then it will do its processing and then unlock it, get the next node and then delete the first node.  This way serialization is limited to those times when the packet processor has caught up to the socket stream class.

So now my question is, before I do the work of actually implementing this, does this sound like a good idea?  I've tried it on a trivial test and it seems to work alright an I can't think of any serious issues with this as long as I implement exception handling and take care to free any memory I allocate, but if anyone can think of any problems with this idea that I've overlooked I would appreciate the input.  Also I would appreciate any other suggestions anyone might have either as an alternative or that might make this idea work better.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This implementation is screaming three things at me:

- Way too easy to get deadlock because insert and delete will need to lock multiple mutexes simultaneously, and you can't do that simultaneously. Well, you can, but you would need to put mutexes around your mutexes.
- Way too easy to get corruption. The problems that lead to deadlock can also lead to corruption.
- And slow, slow, slow. Think of your poor list walker. Each step involves an unlock, a lock, another unlock, and another lock. is going to have to be very careful in stepping, and man, will it be expensive. Lock and unlock each item, and do so in the correct order? Ouch.

This looks like a case of premature optimization and premature pessimization operating in parallel. What drove this architecture?

I suggest starting with the simple solution first. Lock the whole thing each time whenever you want to touch any part of it. See if that gets you in trouble. If it doesn't, problem solved. If it does, a next step up is to switch from mutexes to read-write locks. Just one, not a gazillion. Now you have to think a bit about whether you want a shared or exclusive lock. If you have been diligent about const-correctness, try using a shared lock (read lock) for your const methods, an exclusive lock (write lock) for your non-const methods.

Comment: After thinking about this a little more it has occurred to me that the first issue is impossible as the stream thread creates the object before the packet processor thread gets the object and it always locks one node ahead before releasing the next node that the packet processor can do work on making deadlocks impossible unless there is nothing for the packet processor to work on yet.

Comment: The next one is equally impossible for the same reason if it's the deadlocks that lead to corruption.  And the third is a nonissue since I'm doing no more locking and unlocking this way than I would be if I were locking and unlocking an entire container except this has the benefit of less memory overhead, no copying my objects into the queue and no potential move operations on the memory in the entire container as the container is automatically resized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you suggest will work. Remember that when you delete a node from a linked list, you need to update the other nodes that point to the deleted node. Similarly, when you add a node you also need to update other nodes to point at the new node. So just locking the node being deleted or added isn't enough.

There are lock-free queues, but they are fiendishly difficult to get correct. For instance, look at the initial comments to the article [here](http://drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/208801974) describing the extra work required to get a published algorithm to work.

Comment: The linked list is one directional.  Each node only points to the next node so when I move forward and then delete the current node there's nothing pointing back to the node I deleted so this isn't an issue.

Comment: Imagine there is one element in the list. At that moment the producer thread tries to add a new node and the consumer thread tries to delete the single element. The producer thread will update the new node to point at the node being deleted. Both threads will try to update the variable pointing at the first element in the list.

Comment: This is why the stream thread always locks the last element in the list so that the processor thread can't do anything to it.  I also intend for it to always make a next element once it's done processing so that there's never a node that the packet processor thread could do work on except that it can't access it because the stream thread owns the lock.

Comment: Reading the description above again, it sounds like both threads are locking nodes at the same end of the list. Is this true? If so, why do you think that this is any more efficient than just having a single mutex for the entire counter? Either way, there is (at least) one mutext that must be locked by both threads during list updates. (Actually, in your case, the producer thread locks two mutexes.)

Comment: No the stream thread locks nodes at the end of the list and the packet processor thread locks nodes at the beginning.  And yes the producer will usually have two nodes locked but only at the beginning of the loop does it do two locks.  The two threads only try to lock the same node in the event that the packet processor completely catches up to the socket stream thread.

Comment: Then go back to my original example where there is just a single node in the list, so the double-node locking doesn't matter. In this case, both threads need to update the variable pointing to the first element in the list: one thread needs to set it to a newly-created node and the other needs to set it to null.

Comment: the first element is destroyed when the packet processor is done with it and the list is only a forward pointing list so there was never anything pointing to it once it became the first element.

Comment: I'm talking about the member of the list object that points at the first node in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are calling this a linked list, this is, in effect, a queue.

It is possible to implement Single Producer Single Consumer lock-free queues, if you are willing to use a fixed-size buffer. This let you control the memory usage at the cost of making the Producer wait if the Consumer is not fast enough.

Apart from this slight point, your design looks fine; it will probably be easier to get it right than the lock-free alternative.

Do remember to have a termination condition (a null pointer in the `next` field for example) so that the Producer may signal to the Consumer that there is no more things to process.

Comment: That's a good idea regarding the termination condition.  I hadn't thought of that so I'll make sure I include it in my final implementation.  And yes it is effectively a queue, I just didn't like having to lock the entire container every time one thread will be pushing or the other popping.  And this would be necessary even for reading and writing as the std::queue and even Microsoft's new concurrency_queue can't guarantee that the containers will occupy the same memory from one call to the next.  Plus all the memory overhead of copying to the buffer and...

Comment: ...potentially moving the entire buffer in memory struck me as very unappealing.

Comment: @jacobkaulike: you are mistaking the Abstraction and a given Implementation. If you design a type in which objects flow one way (ie pushed on one side and popped from the other) and it is not possible to access objects in the middle, then you have a Queue, whether it is implemented using a dynamic array or a linked-list does not change it. Note that you could Microsoft's `concurrency_queue` by storing pointers to your objects instead of the objects themselves to solve the memory issues (objects moving around and large buffer).

Comment: Using Microsoft's concurrency_queue to store pointers would only solve half of the memory issues.  There would still be no guarantee that the address of the container is the same and so locking the entire queue for pushing and popping instead of just the node being worked on currently would still be necessary.  Which I am aware concurrency_queue does for you in its try_pop and push calls, but it's still more locking than I really need.

Comment: And point taken on the mistaking abstraction for a given implementation thing.  What I am going to implement will be a queue just not a standard implementation of one...or one implemented in any standard libraries anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. why such a complex solution to a common problem?  There are plenty of producer-consumer queue classes out there - pick a reference/pointer/int sized one that works, (ie. no data copying).

Get bytes from your stream until you have assembled a 'packet object' according to your protocol.  Shove the packet object *reference* onto the queue and immediately new() another one for the next packet.  The packet processor consumes packet objects from the queue.

The queue is only locked for the time taken to push/pop an object reference to/from the queue.  The packet object being assembled by the socket/stream callback and the packet object being processed by the packet processor are always different, so no locking required.

Trying to operate on objects that are already in the queue, (or queue-like linked-list), sounds like a nightmare to me, (and the other posters seem to agree).  Is there some other reason why you need to do this?

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: The trivial test of this concept which I tried showed me that operating on the objects already in the queue will be easy, I just step up the list and operate on the node I'm at then get the next node and delete the current node when I'm done.  The main advantage I was looking for is that the socket stream will always have priority and will never have to wait for the packet processor to finish to do what it needs to do.  My primary objective was to give the socket stream priority.  In a concurrent_queue this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: OK, I get that, but I would be amazed if a concurrent_queue push of a 32/64-bit reference and the signaling of a synchro object, (condvar, semaphore, monitor,whatever), took more than 1uS on a modern CPU/OS, assuming no contention. I'm gussing that the assembly of a packet object, (including the network stack/driver activity), takes much longer than that, on average.  Are your packet objects very small and network very fast?

Comment: I think the memory reallocation and possibly relocation that will continuously happen, though, as the concurrent_queue has to be dynamically resized will use up more cycles than my alternative, though.

Comment: Well, dunno how it works in C++ vectors.  Mostly, dynamic lists are upsized on powers of 2.  When they are downsized, I don't know, quite possibly never.  You can avoid continual reallocation, and certainly relocation, by creating a pool of packet objects at startup and pushing them onto a pool queue, (another thread-safe P-C queue), sucking them off in your stream-handler as required and releasing them after your packet-processor has done with them.  There is no new/dispose, no reallocation, no relocation and the memory use is contained.